# ReCAPTCHA siteverify not returning JSON response

Tags: node.js, recaptcha

I am implementing recaptcha into a user submittable form. After attempting to validate the token using the url

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
```

The response given is something similar to

```
▼���RPP*.MNN-.V�RHK�)N�☺��▬§�↨�&秤�ģ�B@�̼�Ĝ�¶�̼��↕ݢ�����T%�d,W-�
�       K
```

The code used to attempt to validate the response is as follows

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
        secret: process.env.RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
        response: req.body.gcaptcha_response,
    });

    var config = {
        method: "post",
        url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: data,
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                body: response.data,
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I have also attempted with other content types to no success. I have also attempted to follow the answer given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036937/google-recaptcha-getresponse-not-returning-json) thread

Comment: I just started getting this in my code, out of nowhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a workaround for now**

I just realised this is happening for the latest version of `axios`.

If you install `axios` version `1.1` it returns the data as json.

Thread: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298