# Getting weird return data from google captcha v2 siteverify API

Tags: node.js, express, recaptcha, captcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have a Vue-Express application which has signup/signin pages.

On both pages, I use the google captcha v2 invisible setting so I manually call the execute function for which I get a valid token

```
03AEkXODA0y6WEjvR8wd507P9Bnmm63hcOP2gMGJBsuN7PFpFJbeGE3r2M-3btinH4xMIu3OeFnpmLwrwJvlhPbyX7dkCzD_3jnbytUr7wrLC0X55O7qO3wrlF94H2ydekNYPutxvj-XaRKWcq_Dw96B5zSuc7h0xqqJgbao54jqHEB3RC5C0MWPkI6tf44TydsUscwlas9lKHG5tQZYNkOdtVwael4SUJuCvs6A5EADsKnUUKHOvfMX1a3-BUDC3fy1bRmqc7uGrmu-_6UUxNN10-7jR_9Cu9AZq94DGQ8YTnN0OJ0Jl_3w5ehl1HToAkW-RX4xWZsJlprccUm8P2Pk30W_KVGrm7W-N_z9w0c-MdFZfH7qV1xkf_hHO6hidvf_WYB_Sw8fBujV8PihixKSH6DKtsn3rVX4tA9BuyxVTTse4g1skqmpxF4Lp3CjAtzRJWwbtKLYCNHy0cTyIZ2AAR1v9QLMY4Mlz5DXIuFb4YTecvsjlxTG6F09gGjMWrWiQ4H-6q7BfE
```

I then pass this to the express app which calls the google api

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=<recaptcha_secret_key>&response=<token>
```

This gives me a response of 
[image]

The same request if sent via postman gives

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error-codes": [
        "timeout-or-duplicate"
    ]
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong here, any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
How I got the token:

I call the onCaptchaVerified when the signin button is clicked and it is called again by the captcha component with the valid token

```
<vue-recaptcha
  ref="recaptcha"
  size="invisible"
  verify="onCaptchaVerified"
  expired="onCaptchaExpired"
  sitekey="sitekey"
/>
```

```
async onCaptchaVerified(token) {
  await this.$refs.recaptcha.execute()
  
  if(!token) {
    return false
  }

  console.log("logging in...", token);

  const res = await postRequest('validate-human', {
    token: token
  )}

  console.log(res.data.data)
}
```

Comment: How did you implement the frontend code? I mean, how do you get the `token`?

Comment: I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of this post
[ReCAPTCHA siteverify not returning JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554699/recaptcha-siteverify-not-returning-json-response)

TLDR:

Issue was caused by Axios version 1.2.0
Reverting to 1.1.0 solved the problem.

This might not have occurred if I would have used the fetch API